# Ideal data structure to hold a large tables in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, data-structures

I am using Flask as backend and React as frontend in my application. The application deals with large amounts of data (millions of rows).

When I send the data from backend (stored in a dataframe in python) to frontend, it is in JSON format and is quite fast. But is JSON format stable enough to hold million rows of data?

Are there any ideal data structures for large data like datatables or dataframes which makes it easier to access rows and columns similar to pandas dataframe in javascript or reactJS?

Comment: Just a side note: while I've seen enough questions at SO from developers building  tables millions rows long (and just about that size wide), I'd love to see the human being that finds it convenient working with such tables.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I can see your point. But my application is similar to a business intelligence tool so I need the complete dataset to apply analysis and visualize the data to get insights.

Answer (score 0):

try using lazyloading. It helps you get data on scroll

Comment: For displaying the table, I've already implemented lazyloading. But for keeping the data in the frontend, which data structure library would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Sending millions of rows to frontend and doing analysis in the frontend is not very adequate. Instead you can apply your bi logic in the backend and send results to frontend.

Comment: By analysis i meant visualizing the results sent from backend. Either way I will have to store it in the frontend before visualizing. In that case, which data structure library would be useful for storing it for a short time until it is visualized?